# "Could not complete cursor operation because the set options have changed since the cursor was declared" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have the following stored procedure on a SqlServer database.  It works fine for earlier versions.  But it is not working for the most recent version (SqlServer Express 2012).  The procedure compiles fine.  But when running it throws the error message.

I know next to nothing about programming stored procedures on SqlServer.  This was a procedure created over 10 years ago and has always worked.  (but now doesn't).

Any ideas what I need to change to correct it?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [GETBOUND] @mTableName char(20), @FIELD_NAME CHAR(20), @FIELD_VALUE CHAR(50), @DIRECTION CHAR(1), @nRec int , @ADD_COND CHAR(100) AS
  declare @myresult char(50)
  declare @counter numeric
  declare @mDesc char(5)
  declare @mEval char(2)


  if @Direction = 'L' BEGIN
    SELECT @mDesc = ' DESC'
    SELECT @mEval = '<='
  END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT @mDesc = ''
    SELECT @mEval = '>='
  END


  exec('DECLARE THESQL   CURSOR FOR SELECT '+@field_name+' FROM '+@mTableName+'  WHERE '+@ADD_COND+@field_name+@mEval+''''+ @Field_Value+''' order by '+@FIELD_NAME+@mDesc)
  SET ROWCOUNT @nrec

   open THESQL


     fetch THESQL into @myresult

  select @COUNTER = 1

  WHILE (@COUNTER <@nRec)
  BEGIN
     fetch THESQL into @myresult
      SELECT @COUNTER = @COUNTER +1
  END


   close THESQL
  deallocate THESQL
 select @myresult
```

Comment: `SET ROWCOUNT` is now a plan cache key in SQL Server 2012. It compiles different plans when `0` to non zero (`262144` in the [`set_options`](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2011/09/parameter-sniffing-and-plan-reuse-affecting-set-options/))

Comment: So quick fix would be to reverse the order of the `SET ROWCOUNT` and the `exec('DECLARE THESQL`. Though actually I don't see that does anything for you at all anyway. You should probably just rewrite the whole thing from scratch using nested `TOP` or `ROW_NUMBER` though.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Inverting these made it work.  Please formulate it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

I took liberty of rewriting your stored procedure. You have no need for `CURSOR` at all in the end you just return the very last element from the cursor. To do that I just reversed the logic so now it will return `TOP 1` record without cursor.

Additionally I renamed some variable, made them `varchar` instead of `char` and made them bigger. Most my tables are well over 20 character.

I have removed variables that were no longer used.

```
EXEC [ups_GetBound]
    @pTable_Name = 'tables'
   ,@pField_Name = 'name'
   ,@pField_Value = 'MyTable'
   ,@pDirection = 'M'
   ,@pExtra_Condition = ''
   ,@pCounter = 13;


CREATE PROC [ups_GetBound]
    (
     @pTable_Name SYSNAME
    ,@pField_Name SYSNAME
    ,@pField_Value VARCHAR(50)
    ,@pDirection CHAR(1)
    ,@pExtra_Condition VARCHAR(100)
    ,@pCounter INT 
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @mDesc CHAR(5)
           ,@mEval CHAR(2)
           ,@Extra_Condition NVARCHAR(100) = '';

        IF @pDirection = 'L'
            BEGIN
                SELECT @mDesc = ' DESC'
                SELECT @mEval = '<='
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @mDesc = ' '
                SELECT @mEval = '>='
            END

        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
           ,@ParamDefenition NVARCHAR(250);

        SET @ParamDefenition = N'@pField_Value VARCHAR(50),@pCounter INT'

        SET @sql = N'WITH CounterSelect as (SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@pField_Name) 
            + ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY '+ QUOTENAME(@pField_Name) + @mDesc + ') as RowNum' 
            + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@pTable_Name) 
            + ' WHERE '+ @pExtra_Condition + QUOTENAME(@pField_Name) + @mEval + '@pField_Value )' 
            + ' SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@pField_Name) 
            + ' From CounterSelect WHERE RowNum = @pCounter'

        --PRINT @sql
        EXEC sp_executesql
            @sql
           ,@ParamDefenition
           ,@pField_Value
           ,@pCounter
    END
```

Comment: Are you sure this has the same semantics as the original? I didn't spend too long looking at it but assumed it was supposed to find the nth row (where n = `@nRec`) by the highly inefficient method of simply fetching each row and discarding the result. Should use `QUOTENAME` to avoid SQL injection. And `sysname` is best datatype for table and column names.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for pointing out the logic issue, I have fixed it now. I did not realize that he was limiting number of results by `ROWCOUNT` function. Also I changed the variables to `sysname` and added `QUOTENAME` to dynamic SQL

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I made the change that @MartinSmith suggested (reversing the order of the calls).  And this work.  I have not tested what you have posted.  But appreciate your effort.

Comment: No problem, eventually you should rewrite that procedure as `CURSOR` is definitely the wrong way to go on this.

Comment: This answer is a complete waste of time as it does not answer the question of how to fix this error. If he wants to know how to re-write this query, he could ask that and that's the answer you could provide. And anyone looking for an answer to this error is going to be pointed here as it's a top search result so thanks for wasting my time and everyone else that is trying to find an answer to this error.